# Adding Google maps with marker on a Viewpager

Tags: android, google-maps, android-viewpager, maps, fragment

I am trying to create an app that has two tabs.
The first tab contains all my contacts and its working fine. The second tab should contain a map displaying a marker of all the contacts whose location is saved.

Google Map is properly rendered without any errors , however how is it possible to place a marker in it?

This is the Viewpager Fragment:

```
package com.example.contacts_mapapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class ContactMap extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    // Google Map
    private SupportMapFragment googleMap;
    View view;

    public ContactMap() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment ContactMap.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static ContactMap newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        ContactMap fragment = new ContactMap();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact_map, container, false);

        try {
            // Loading map
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();

                googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map));

                googleMap.getMapAsync((OnMapReadyCallback) getActivity());

                // check if map is created successfully or not
                if (googleMap == null) {
                    googleMap = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map,googleMap).commit();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return view;

    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
                .title("Marker in Sydney"));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

XML File:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.contacts_mapapp.ContactMap">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_contact_map"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you are already adding a marker in `onMapReady`, what is the issue?

Comment: I still cannot see the marker

Answer (score 0):

change your `googleMap.getMapAsync((OnMapReadyCallback) getActivity());` to `googleMap.getMapAsync(this);` and lemme know if it fixes your problem.

Comment: welcome. please up-vote and accept the answer if it helped, so it could helpful for someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

assign the googleMap(variable initialized in onCreateView) to your variable googleMap in onMapReady(). that you have initialized in onCreatView

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    googleMap = googleMap;
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
            .title("Marker in Sydney"));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```